# 15.04 VMWare Player "unable to start services" error

Tags: vmware, 15.04

I recently did a fresh install to 15.04. I downloaded and installed vmware player, but when I go to launch it, I receive a message saying "vmware workstation several modules must be compiled and loaded into the kernel."

I click install so that it can proceed, but then I get an error saying that it is "unable to start services."

Any ideas of how I can get it to work again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found here https://communities.vmware.com/thread/509225

This can be fixed by running the following steps as Root (in a terminal):

1. log in as root (e.g. `sudo -i`)
2. Enter your Root password.
3. Enter these commands:

   ```
   curl https://pastebin.com/raw/Z1ihzbcE -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch

   cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
   tar -xf vmnet.tar
   cd vmnet-only
   patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
   mv vmnet.tar vmnet.tar.SAVED
   tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
   rm -r vmnet-only
   vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
   ```

VMware will now compile the vmnet module for Kernel 3.19. (please make sure you have DKMS installed)

Comment: The link http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download seems to be broken.

Comment: work's here. downloaded now
try this url for the curl :
http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=Z1ihzbcE

Comment: In the step `patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch` I got the message: `patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.`

Comment: @student did you find any solution?

Comment: A pastebin patch!? I think I just threw up in my mouth a little.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to upgrade to the latest version of VMware player before trying the patch. While I was on VMware Player 6.x the patch didn't work, but on 7.1.x it worked.

Comment: Thanks! I reinstalled VMware player, and then applied the patch. Worked perfectly :)

Comment: Care to link to the patch you're referring to? I've just updated to Ubuntu 15.04, installed Vmware Player 7.1.0-2496824.x86_64 and I have a "Failed to build vmnet" error as well

Comment: Second naisanza:  What patch are you referring to?  Thanks.

Comment: I found this page, and it worked: http://askubuntu.com/questions/613187/vmware-player-and-ubuntu-15-04-net-driver-does-not-compile-anymore-how-to-fix

Answer (score -1):

This worked well for me:

For the newbies out there, This is what the commands will do by running it in terminal:

- In the folder `/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source`, you have to extract the `vmnet-only` file from `vmnet.tar` and make a backup of the `.tar-file.`
- Run the patch you downloaded from http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download before making a new vmnet.tar from the vmnet-only folder
- Delete the vmnet-only folder and do the compiling

Comment: Can you explain it better? Not for me, but I think that the most of newbies will not understand. You can explain how to use a patch etc.

Comment: Please explain your process more. a step by step process with command line how you finally got yours to work. Thanks for your effort so far