# Unable to install vmware workstation on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: kernel, 15.04, compiling, vmware

When i install VMware workstation on my Ubuntu 15.04 with kernel updated from 3.19 to 4.2 . It shows below path

`/tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-8097.log`

Hence, i go to check the path and find below error in logs

```
2015-09-06T12:35:44.077+05:30| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.2.0-040200rc3-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-09-06T12:35:44.077+05:30| vthread-3| I120: /lib/modules/4.2.0-040200rc3-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
```

Please tell me anyone...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Did you install the kernel headers for  4.2?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/614525/15-04-vmware-player-unable-to-start-services-error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help installing VirtualBox on ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/671189/need-help-installing-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then try installing again

Comment: Nope. The error message says pretty clearly, that header files are missing, not build tools.

Comment: i tried already, but not working

Answer (score 0):

There is some changes in the 4.x kernel series that requires modified sourced for the vmware modules. I have a partial method that doesn't work entirely:

See https://communities.vmware.com/message/2546788 . You can apply it to the unpacked tar files in /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source :

```
    cd ~
    curl -o ~/vmware-modules-linux-4.2.0-rc5+.patch.zip "https://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2529949-140350/vmware-modules-linux-4.2.0-rc5%2B.patch.zip"
    unzip ~/vmware-modules-linux-4.2.0-rc5+.patch.zip
    cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
    ls *.tar | while read file; do tar xf $file; done
    patch -p1 < ~/vmware-modules-linux-4.2.0-rc5+.patch
```

```

But this doesn't apply cleanly. Any further hints are appreciated.