# VMware workstation is not working with GCC 5.1.1

Tags: 15.04, compiling, vmware, gcc

Ubuntu 15.04
GCC 5.1.1

---

After installing ubuntu 15.04 vmware is no longer working with gcc 5.1.1

While trying to launch vmware workstation I get an error.

Tried to push refresh, nothing happens... also tried to add this path

```
/usr/lib/gcc/
```

and any sub-path but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VMware on Ubuntu 15.10 - GNU C Compiler (gcc) version 4.9.2 was not found](//askubuntu.com/a/733498)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VMWare player and Ubuntu 15.04: net driver does not compile anymore, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613187/vmware-player-and-ubuntu-15-04-net-driver-does-not-compile-anymore-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by downgrading GCC in my Ubuntu here it is ..
1 - Uninstall GCC 5.1.1 :

```
sudo apt-get remove gcc-5
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gcc-5
sudo apt-get purge gcc-5
```

2 - install gcc 4.9.2

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
```

3 - make a link to your gcc 4.9.2

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/bin/gcc
ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.9 /usr/bin/g++
```

4 - open VMware and it will run perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Compile manually..

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
sudo tar -xvf vmnet.tar
cd vmnet-only
sudo make
cd ..
sudo tar -xvf vmmon.tar
cd vmmon-only
sudo make
cd ..
sudo mkdir /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc/
sudo cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc/vmmon.ko
sudo cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc/vmnet.ko
sudo depmod -a
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart
```