# VMWare Player not working with Linux kernel 4.2.5

Tags: vmware, gcc

I m using Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4. Due to some reasons I need to upgrade to kernel 4.2.5. But after that VMWare Player(i believe version 12.x 64 bit linux) is not working. At the time of start up it is trying to compile the modules for the the new kernel. I uninstalled it and did a fresh install of VMWare Player but the same issue. It is looking for particular version of gcc which is not available.[image: screenshot]

Looked into this thread also [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642507/vmware-workstation-is-not-working-with-gcc-5-1-1)
but not able to located gcc-5.2.1 version. Also not able to uninstall the previous version of gcc

This is my current version of gcc

```
root@ashu-HP-ENVY-Notebook:/var/log/vmware# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
```

And here are the vmware logs

```
2016-01-24T02:40:12.095-07:00| usbArb| I125: Log for VMware USB Arbitration Service pid=2248 version=12.1.0 build=build-3215723 option=Release
2016-01-24T02:40:12.095-07:00| usbArb| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.095-07:00| usbArb| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2016-01-24T02:40:12.095-07:00| usbArb| I125: Host is Linux 4.2.5-040205-generic Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
2016-01-24T02:40:12.094-07:00| usbArb| I125: VTHREAD initialize main thread 3 "usbArb" tid 2248
2016-01-24T02:40:12.094-07:00| usbArb| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.094-07:00| usbArb| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.094-07:00| usbArb| I125: Could not expand environment variable HOME.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.094-07:00| usbArb| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "~/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.094-07:00| usbArb| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at ~/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.094-07:00| usbArb| I125: Could not expand environment variable HOME.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.094-07:00| usbArb| I125: PREF Disabling user preferences because disableUserPreferences is set.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.094-07:00| usbArb| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- GLOBAL SETTINGS /usr/lib/vmware/settings 
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- NON PERSISTENT
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- USER PREFERENCES
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- USER DEFAULTS ~/.vmware/config 
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- HOST DEFAULTS /etc/vmware/config 
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT                NETWORKING = "yes"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT            VMBLOCK_CONFED = "yes"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT           gksu.rootMethod = "sudo"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT                    libdir = "/usr/lib/vmware"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT               VMCI_CONFED = "yes"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT              VSOCK_CONFED = "yes"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT             initscriptdir = "/etc/init.d"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT            authd.fullpath = "/usr/sbin/vmware-authd"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT                    bindir = "/usr/bin"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT installerDefaults.componentDownloadEnabled = "yes"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT installerDefaults.autoSoftwareUpdateEnabled.epoch = "8058385214"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT        vix.config.version = "1"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT    player.product.version = "12.1.0"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT installerDefaults.dataCollectionEnabled.epoch = "7384059603"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT installerDefaults.dataCollectionEnabled = "yes"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT installerDefaults.transferVersion = "1"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT installerDefaults.autoSoftwareUpdateEnabled = "yes"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT       product.buildNumber = "3272444"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT --- SITE DEFAULTS /usr/lib/vmware/config 
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT                  tag.help = "introduction.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT   tag.configurationEditor = "config_editor_newvm.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT             tag.ideConfig = "devices_virtualdrive.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT          tag.floppyConfig = "devices_floppy.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT           tag.mouseConfig = "devices_mouse.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT             tag.netConfig = "devices_netadapter.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT        tag.parallelConfig = "devices_parallel.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT          tag.serialConfig = "devices_serial.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT           tag.soundConfig = "devices_sound.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT             tag.memConfig = "configvm_memory.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT            tag.miscConfig = "configvm.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT             tag.usbConfig = "devices_usb.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT         tag.displayConfig = "configvm_display-problems.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: DICT                 tag.tools = "vmtools.htm"
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: USBArbRuleStore: Loading device rules from '/etc/vmware/usbarb.rules'.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: VMware USB Arbitration Service Version 15.1.7
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: USBGL: USB Sysfs found at /dev/bus/usb
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: USBArb: Attempting to connect to existing arbitrator on /var/run/vmware/usbarbitrator-socket.
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: SOCKET creating new socket, connecting to /var/run/vmware/usbarbitrator-socket
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: SOCKET connect failed, error 2: No such file or directory
2016-01-24T02:40:12.148-07:00| usbArb| I125: USBArb: Failed to connect to the existing arbitrator.
```

Comment: Have you tries making ensuring that the build-essentials and headers are loaded?  `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic`

Comment: @Charles Green . I already have the latest version of it. sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: K - there is an odd post on the vmware community forums about using a newer kernel - I will type it as an answer, as it is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was lifted from the [vmware community forum](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/514195?start=0&tstart=0) and describes manually compiling the VMWare services because the kernel being used is newer than the distro available.

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
unpack vmnet.tar
cd vmnet-only
make
cd ..
unpack vmmon.tar
cd vmmon-only
make
cd ..
cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmmon.ko
cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmnet.ko
depmod -a
/etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

Comment: thx...but it's still not working...i installed gcc-5 but it's failing...have started following up on that thread only.

Comment: thanks. Your answer required gcc 5.x. After installing gcc-5.1(it's called only gcc-5 as ubuntu/linux ignore the minor version at the time of update). Once i did that and updated the /usr/bin/gcc to point to /usr/bin/gcc-5(ln -s command). Then i just started VMWare Player and it started working(it did all the compilation of the modules on it's own(i am using VMWare Player 12.x) Now it's working as usual. My newer kernel(4.2.5) should have gcc-5 for most of the stuff like VMWare to work with.