# I'm using Ubuntu for the first time(Ubuntu 15.04). Does Ubuntu support virtualization?

Tags: virtualization

I am installing Ubuntu 15.04. I just wanted to know whether is supports virtualization. I also wanted to know whether I can run virtualization softwares like VMWare, VirtualBox or any others if available for this version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
VMWare Player for Linux exists and unless there's a bug specifically with 15.04, it'll run. Literally watched someone run VMWare Player today on Ubuntu.
VirtualBox runs on Linux too. I'm assuming Ubuntu.

VMWare Download Page:
https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free
Scroll to bottom and try installing VMware Player

(PROTIP: if it's 32bit, crank the release down to 6)

Comment: Note vmnet with VMware Player has had bugs with your version of Ubuntu. Described here http://askubuntu.com/questions/613187/vmware-player-and-ubuntu-15-04-net-driver-does-not-compile-anymore-how-to-fix

Comment: OK. I'm using a 64 bit version, the bug you said, is it there even with latest version of VMWare?

Comment: I honestly don't know to be frank. I just tried to see if there was a bug. I haven't had a lot of experience specifically with 15.04 and VMware, just Ubuntu and VMware

Answer (score 2):

Use virtualbox,you can intall it directly from ubuntu repository via apt-get install virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox and VMware support Linux platform, install them using following command :

**VirtualBox**

32-Bit :

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.2/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_i386.deb
cd Downloads/ && sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_i386.deb
```

64-Bit :

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.2/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb
cd Downloads/ && sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb
```

**VMWare**

First install `build-essential` and `linux-headers` package :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Go to [VMware download page](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0) and select your file :

[image]

Run following command once the download proccess complete :

32-Bit :

```
cd Downloads/ && sudo chmod +x VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.i386.bundle
sudo ./VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.i386.bundle
```

64-Bit :

```
cd Downloads/ && sudo chmod +x VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle
sudo ./VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle
```