# vmplayer doesn't build on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: compiling, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 then as root I'm using vmware 64 bit. I have already tried reinstall via the vmware installer.

When I launch vmplayer

```
Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Blocking file system                                                done
   Virtual ethernet                                                    failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
```

When I build there is the followig error (see below)

```
tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/driver.c:1239:20: error: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’
```

Any ideas? I tried:

```
$ sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-17-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-17-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1342:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
 LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
 ^
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-17-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-17-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-17-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/filter.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/filter.c:48:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/filter.c:20:
include/linux/printk.h:105:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/filter.c:207:1: error: conflicting types for ‘VNetFilterHookFn’
 VNetFilterHookFn(const struct nf_hook_ops *ops,        // IN:
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/filter.c:64:18: note: previous declaration of ‘VNetFilterHookFn’ was here
 static nf_hookfn VNetFilterHookFn;
                  ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/smac_compat.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/smac_compat.c:33:
include/linux/printk.h:105:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/filter.c:64:18: warning: ‘VNetFilterHookFn’ used but never defined
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/filter.c:207:1: warning: ‘VNetFilterHookFn’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 VNetFilterHookFn(const struct nf_hook_ops *ops,        // IN:
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/driver.c:51:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/driver.c:23:
include/linux/printk.h:105:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/procfs.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/procfs.c:23:
include/linux/printk.h:105:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/filter.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/filter.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/hub.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/hub.c:23:
include/linux/printk.h:105:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/driver.c: In function ‘VNetFileOpUnlockedIoctl’:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/driver.c:1239:20: <b>error: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’</b>
    if (filp && filp->f_dentry) {
                    ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/driver.c:1240:19: error: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’
       inode = filp->f_dentry->d_inode;
                   ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/userif.c:45:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from include/linux/list.h:8,
                 from include/linux/wait.h:6,
                 from include/linux/fs.h:6,
                 from include/linux/highmem.h:4,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
include/linux/printk.h:105:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/userif.c: In function ‘VNetCopyDatagram’:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/userif.c:526:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘skb_copy_datagram_iovec’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    return skb_copy_datagram_iovec(skb, 0, &iov, len);
           ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c:23:
include/linux/printk.h:105:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/driver.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/driver.o] Error 1
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
include/linux/pci_ids.h:2252:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD
 ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c: In function ‘VNetNetIf_Create’:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c:152:64: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
    dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof *netIf, deviceName, VNetNetIfSetup);
                                                                ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c:152:10: error: ‘alloc_netdev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof *netIf, deviceName, VNetNetIfSetup);
          ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c:152:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c: At top level:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.c:85:1: warning: ‘VNetNetIfSetup’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 VNetNetIfSetup(struct net_device *dev)  // IN:
 ^
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/netif.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/monitorAction_exported.h:31:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnet.h:29,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_assert.h:259:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined
    #define DEPRECATED(_fix) do {} while (0)
 ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.c:23:
include/linux/printk.h:105:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define DEPRECATED "[Deprecated]: "
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD
 ^
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.c:51:
include/linux/pci_ids.h:2252:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.c:50:0:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.c: In function ‘VNetBridgeUp’:
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h:81:40: error: too few arguments to function ‘sk_alloc’
 #   define compat_sk_alloc(_bri, _pri) sk_alloc(&init_net, \
                                        ^
/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.c:952:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘compat_sk_alloc’
    bridge->sk = compat_sk_alloc(bridge, GFP_ATOMIC);
                 ^
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/compat_sock.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.c:35:
include/net/sock.h:1515:14: note: declared here
 struct sock *sk_alloc(struct net *net, int family, gfp_t priority,
              ^
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/bridge.o] Error 1
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/userif.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only/userif.o] Error 1
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-17-generic'
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-RTj6zp/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

Comment: Which version of VMWare are you trying to run?

Comment: VMware-Player-6.0.6-2700073.x86_64.bundle

Comment: I think you should really consider downloading a more recent version.  Given that the player is free for personal use, do you need V 6?  The current version is `VMware-Player-12.0.1-3160714.x86_64.bundle`

Comment: Thank's a lot I've installed VMware-Player-12.0.1-3160714.x86_64.bundle and now vmplayer starts.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be, to me, a case where VMware hasn't updated their software yet for the latest kernel, so it's entirely possible it can't build under this version.  It also appears it's relying on functions that aren't 'common' anymore.

There may be patches online, however you are going to faces some headaches and such going forward.  I would reach out to VMware to see if they have a solution currently, as there's not much we can really do right now...

Answer (score 0):

VMPlayer 7 has a known issue with patches, as referred to in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613187/vmware-player-and-ubuntu-15-04-net-driver-does-not-compile-anymore-how-to-fix), and VMPlayer 12, the current version, has a bug referred to in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689123/vmware-wont-work-after-ubuntu-upgrade/689135#689135).

I would suggest that you download the current VMPlayer from vmware.com, and modify the wrapper file so that vmplayer will execute:

Open a terminal window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, and enter the following command

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/vmplayer
```

scroll down a few lines to a line which says `set -e`

Input a new line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save and exit, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have the same error when I start the vmplayer

Comment: @GrazianoNatali The version of VMPlayer that you are running is simply too old for either of these fixes.  I could search, but I do not think that patches exist for the old version.  Do you need a link for the new version for download?

Comment: Thank's a lot I've installed VMware-Player-12.0.1-3160714.x86_64.bundle and now vmplayer starts.

Comment: This solution was valid for 15.04; not working in 15.10.

Comment: @HydraStarmaster I did not have a problem with VMWare in 15.04 - when 15.10 rolled out this became necessary for me.